# jQuery validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, validation

All that I've searched didn't work. I'm a newbie in jQuery and I'm trying to develop a little register form. The AJAX is OK, but the browser is just ignoring my validation. I guess it's a stupid error, but I can't find it.

My jQuery: http://pastebin.com/GyvbCDMB

My HTML: http://pastebin.com/ziqsBSAb

Thanks any help.

Answer (score 0):

I got. In rules, I must declare the element's names, not the ids. Just it.